# How to make an object fly disabling gravity through C# script in unity

Tags: unity, physics

I want to make an object fly which has ridged body physics by disabling its gravity after pressing a key.
So I just want to know how to disable gravity through C# script. I already went through google search but I didn’t get what I want. I even tried this link    http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html

Comment: `other.attachedRigidbody.useGravity = false;` - Is it that hard to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like this. its simple

```
    public GameObject YourGameobject;//refrence of your gameobject
    void Update()
    {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))//on W input it will disable the gravit of your desire object
        {
            YourGameobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        }
    }
```

You can change [KeyCode](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html).W into according to your requirement